# Copying files and renaming files into the original folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I am very new to the scripting process. I've been googling my problem for over a week, and have found snippets of pieces of what I need, but I can't figure out how to put it all together.

I need help with the following:

```
FOLDER1/main.txt

FOLDER1/SUBFOLDER/main.txt

FOLDER2/main.txt

FOLDER3/main.txt
```

I would need to make a copy of main.txt and rename it to temp.txt into the same folder...
(Except, I have a thousand of these files to do!)

So I would have something like this:

```
FOLDER1
> main.txt
> temp.txt
FOLDER1/SUBFOLDER
> main.txt
> temp.txt

FOLDER2
> main.txt
> temp.txt

FOLDER3
> main.txt
> temp.txt
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -Filter 'main.txt' -Recurse | % {
  Copy-Item $_.FullName (Join-Path $_.Directory 'temp.txt')
}
```

In batch:

```
@echo off

for /r "C:\some\folder" %%f in (main.txt) do (
  copy "%%~ff" "%%~dpftemp.txt"
)
```